# Hibernate Envers: Initializing Envers Proxies

Tags: java, hibernate, proxy, lazy-loading, hibernate-envers

In Hibernate Envers, all related collections of an entity are loaded lazily, regardless of what fetch type is set. So when auditquerying for an entity that has a collection of other entities (both audited, of course), the collection is a `SetProxy` at first (can be seen when debugging).

So, how do I initialize that proxy? Using `Hibernate.initialize()` has no effect (I suspect because Hibernate and Envers are using different proxy objects). I know I can initialize the set by iterating over its items, but that isn't an option for me because I have multiple collections in an entity and not to mention the maintenance issues.

I need to initialize them eagerly because I'm accessing the collection at a later point in time when the Hibernate session is already closed (converting the domain objects into dtos).

I'm using Hibernate 3.5.6.

Comment: I can't get this sh!t to work either! Envers seems to ignore the fetch plan! I have several entities set to eager fetch with a SELECT fetch mode (because I know they are always in the 2nd level cache - read only and eternal). I am getting lazy initialization errors when rendering the JSPs. PAIN IN THE YOU-KNOW-WHAT. :( Grrr!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently, this is an open issue with Hibernate Envers. There is already an existing issue in their JIRA: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3552. Feel free to vote on it, maybe it will speed things up, when they see that there are some people wanting this to be fixed ;)

Until the Envers team fixes this issue, there is a work around which works for me: Calling `size()` on the collections initializes the proxy objects.

Comment: Hibernate.initialize() didn't work for us too. Only #size() saved us.

Answer (score 4):

The best workaround I've found so far for initializing the Envers proxies is to use [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). Mapping the audited entity returned by Envers to itself forces the initialization.

For example:

```
    // Assuming you have an initialized EntityManager in entityManager & 
    // id contains your entity id..

    List<Object[]> auditList = (List<Object[]>)AuditReaderFactory.
                                   get(entityManager).
                                   createQuery().
                                   forRevisionsOfEntity(Foo.class, false, true).
                                   add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id)).
                                   getResultList();

    // Use a singleton in production apps instead...
    DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();

    for(Object[] audit : auditList) {
        audit[0] = mapper.map(audit[0], Foo.class);
    }

    // The proxies in the Foo instances in auditList are now initialized
```

I'm not very happy with this solution, but I prefer it over initializing the proxies by manually touching the collections. Hope someone comes up with a better alternative or HHH-3552 gets fixed!

Comment: Good solution but watch out for bugs caused by failure to observe correct getter and setter naming for all properties in all classes of the whole object graph.  An example error can be for boolean properties, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322648/for-a-boolean-field-what-is-the-naming-convention-for-its-getter-setter

Answer (score -3):

There's something wrong with your design.

If you need to initialize them inside an interceptor (I suspect Envers works by intercepting hibernate calls), it means that you need to **know** about your domain model beforehand. Auditing should be a completely independeny concern from domain modeling.

Having this said, you can roll your own initializer using some generic reflection method for iterating the collection, or you can use the *Open-Session-In-View* pattern and adapt it to work with Envers (ie, inside your interceptor).

Bear in mind that accessing these items will probably trigger other queries, which can be confusing if you analyze the logs.

---

**Edit**:
It seems that hibernate has fetch profiles, which can let you choose a fetch plan at runtime.
See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207510/spring-transactional-and-hibernate-lazy-loading) and the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-profiles).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "initializing them inside an interceptor". After all, I am getting the domain objects as it is supposed to by the Envers API (executing an AutitQuery via the AuditReader). However, my problem is indeed an open issue (http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3552) as I found out later.

Comment: Got the same issue. How did you get around it in the end?

Comment: There is some kind of work around. You have to call `size()` on the collections. The Envers proxy objects will then be initialized.