# For a boolean field, what is the naming convention for its getter/setter?

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions, javabeans

Eg.

```
boolean isCurrent = false;
```

What do you name its getter and setter?

Comment: I assume you are refering to JavaBeans in which case @Jigar Joshi's answer is correct. However if you are asking about generic getter/setters, the only convension is that the methods contain the field's name and the getter takes no arguments and returns a value, the setter takes one argument and returns no value or returns the object itself. see Buffer as a example of another approach to getter/setters.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

Suppose you have

```
boolean active;
```

Accessors method would be

```
public boolean isActive(){return this.active;}

public void setActive(boolean active){this.active = active;}
```

---

**See Also**

- [Java Programming/Java Beans](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Java_Beans)
- [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Comment: Could you point the section of Sun's code conventions where boolean getter names are specifically covered? I could not find it.

Comment: I have a  **boolean** filed named `hasCustomName`, Now what should i name for it's **getter** and **setter** methods? Is `setHasCustomName[setter]` and `hasCustomName[getter]` good?

Comment: @Hadi

just name your variable "customerName" and generate getter n setter for it.
Expected getter and setters are 

`public boolean isCustomerName(){return this.customerName;}

public void setCustomerName(boolean customerName){this.customerName= customerName;}`

Comment: how'd we get from custom name to customer name? ;)

Comment: @Assegd Naming it "customerName" or "customName" is confusing and does not denote that it is boolean. Seeing the variable I'd expect it to contain a name. In this case, it should be called "hasCustomName" IMO.

Comment: @Nathan
 i was totally concentrating on giving the right answer regarding to the getters and setters. Naming the boolean variable does make more sense when it contains conformation words like "has"

Comment: Here, the field is named `active` and the getter is named `isActive`. What to do if _active_ is a local variable? How to name it then?

Comment: local variables don't have accessor method.

Answer (score 123):

http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html#Specific

> 14. *`is`* prefix should be used for boolean variables and methods.
>
>     `isSet`, `isVisible`, `isFinished`, `isFound`, `isOpen`
>
> This is the naming convention for
>   boolean methods and variables used by
>   **Sun for the Java core packages.**  Using the is prefix solves a common
>   problem of choosing bad boolean names
>   like status or flag. isStatus or
>   isFlag simply doesn't fit, and the
>   programmer is forced to chose more
>   meaningful names.
>
> Setter methods for boolean variables
>   must have set prefix as in:
>
> ```
> void setFound(boolean isFound);
> ```
>
> There are a few alternatives to the is
>   prefix that fits better in some
>   situations. These are has, can and
>   should prefixes:
>
> ```
> boolean hasLicense(); 
> boolean canEvaluate(); 
> boolean shouldAbort = false;
> ```

Comment: So if there is the boolean property `hasData`, what would the setter look like? Most certainly, `setData(bool hasData)` looks awfully wrong to me...

Comment: @FranzB. I'd use setHasData(...)

Comment: For those who want to follows JavaBeans specifcation, it seems that `has`, `can`, `should` prefixes are not part of the specification. Reference [JavaBeans Specification 1.01](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) section 8.3.

Comment: @Andrew hi. When I am using 'is' prefix in my variable and sending the value of that variable from my js file in the data, it is always giving me the value as false. And if I remove 'is' prefix than it is working absolutely fine. What can be the reason for that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Learner Ask a separate question and share a link with me, please. I will have a look. I have no idea how you are sending, what you are sending.

Comment: The setter is straightforward, for the getter I had to use `boolean isIsCurrent(){...}` otherwise the framework used to deserialize the object, was complaining with `getter not found for property isCurrent`.

Comment: @VCD "it seems that has, can, should prefixes are not part of the specification" - Hence, that's the whole problem with blindly trying to follow these types of specifications. They usually just cover basic scenarios. The main thing is, use intuitive variable and method names that make sense and that people maintaining this code later will understand. Common sense goes a long way here.

Comment: @FranzB. The "hasData()" method would not be bound to a property. It's result would be calculated from the object state. E.g. "checking if data-stream can be read without blocking." The "shouldAbortg" is bad naming since if it was bound to a setter method, it would be "is/SetAbortRequested()" thus would conform to standard convention.

Answer (score 88):

For a field named `isCurrent`, the correct getter / setter naming is `setCurrent()` / `isCurrent()` (at least that's what Eclipse thinks), which is highly confusing and can be traced back to the main problem:

**Your field should not be called `isCurrent` in the first place.** *Is* is a verb and verbs are inappropriate to represent an Object's state. Use an adjective instead, and suddenly your getter / setter names will make more sense:

```
private boolean current;

public boolean isCurrent(){
    return current;
}

public void setCurrent(final boolean current){
    this.current = current;
}
```

Comment: What if the boolean is not a primitive? If it is Boolean should it be a get or is?

Comment: No, such a method could return null, which would cause a NullPointerException. But I would try to avoid returning Boolean in the first place

Comment: @Arun I think it should be set/get instead if set/is because of Boolean is an object instead of primitive, because it has 3 stats, false, true or null.

Comment: IntelliJ defaults to using `get` prefix when retrieving a `Boolean` vs `is` for a `boolean`

Comment: @jocull and that is the correct behavior, according to the JavaBeans specification

Comment: Seems like Eclipse updated its naming convention for booleans: `is prefix should be used for boolean variables and methods.` https://wiki.eclipse.org/Recommenders/CodingConventions#is_prefix_should_be_used_for_boolean_variables_and_methods.

Comment: I agree with the advice for practical reasons (having a different name for the variable and getter), but not the reasoning. *Is* and *has* are stative verbs, and are fine to use for naming boolean properties. It's active verbs specifically that should be reserved for functions.

Comment: Here, the field is named `current` and the getter is named `isCurrent`. What to do if _current_ is a local variable? How to name it then?

Answer (score 8):

I [believe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean) it would be:

```
void setCurrent(boolean current)
boolean isCurrent()
```

Comment: I like that convention, but conventions don't really matter. The most important is to stick with the one you chose.

Comment: @Clement Conventions *do* matter when you rely on tools that use these conventions. JavaBeans is a convention with wide support in plenty libraries (JSP / JSF / Spring / Groovy just to name a few). Breaking the conventions means breaking the way these libraries work.

Comment: @Sean Right, excepted for framework that rely on conventions over configuration. In this case conventions are imposed by the framework, so you don't chose anything. Good remark.

Answer (score 7):

There is a markable point between ***setter/getter*** method of the data type **Boolean** and **boolean** in side a class ( for *pojo/entity*).

- For both Boolean and boolean the *setter* method should be ***setXXX()*** but *getter* method would be ***getXXX()*** and ***isXXX()*** respectively

**Example:**

**(a)** if property is defines as **Boolean**

```
private Boolean check;
```

the setter/getter method

```
public Boolean getCheck() {   // getXXX()
    return check;
}

public void setCheck(Boolean check) {
    this.check = check;
}
```

**(b)** if property is defines as **boolean**

```
private boolean check;
```

the setter/getter method

```
   public boolean isCheck() {   // isXXX()
        return check;
    }
    public void setCheck(boolean check) {
        this.check = check;
    }
```

Comment: Presumably, this is because if you _get_ a Boolean, you may want to do something complicated with it, like `compareTo`, or `toString`. It would be a bit weird to say; `myThing.isWibble().toString()`. But if you get a boolean, all you can do is test it; `if (myThing.isWibble()) doWibble();`

Comment: Here, the field is named `check` and the getter is named either `getCheck` or `isCheck`. What to do if _check_ is a local variable? How to name it then?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it is time to start revising this answer? Personally I would vote for `setActive()` and `unsetActive()` (alternatives can be `setUnActive()`, `notActive()`, `disable()`, etc. depending on context) since "setActive" implies you activate it at all times, which you don't. It's kind of counter intuitive to say "setActive" but actually remove the active state.

Another problem is, you can can not listen to specifically a SetActive event in a CQRS way, you would need to listen to a 'setActiveEvent' and determine inside that listener wether is was actually set active or not. Or of course determine which event to call when calling `setActive()` but that then goes against the Separation of Concerns principle.

A good read on this is the FlagArgument article by Martin Fowler: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html

However, I come from a PHP background and see this trend being adopted more and more. Not sure how much this lives with Java development.

Answer (score 2):

It should just be get{varname} like every other getter.  Changing it to "is" doesn't stop bad variable names, it just makes another unnecessary rule.

Consider program generated code, or reflection derivations.

It's a non-useful convention that should be dropped at the first available opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended to use an **adjective** to name a boolean field. If you generate getter and setter using IntelliJ, you will find out that the getter is `isCurrent()` for both of boolean fields `current` and `isCurrent`.

We can take a look at [IntelliJ community source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/lombok/testData/after/getter/GetterBoolean.java), its test data shows that no matter whether your boolean field name starts with `is` or not, the name of getter starts with `is`.

```
class Getter {
  boolean foo;
  boolean isBar;
  boolean hasBaz;

  @java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")
  public boolean isFoo() {
      return this.foo;
  }

  @java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")
  public boolean isBar() {
      return this.isBar;
  }

  @java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")
  public boolean isHasBaz() {
      return this.hasBaz;
  }
}
```

It will be very confusing when you want to call the getter, when you boolean field name starts with `is`. Besides, when your colleagues want to get the value of a boolean field you defined, they will only know the getter' s name instead of the field' s name. In that case, the prefix `is` is not necessary.

Here is another example, when I retrieve data from database to instantiate a object of Employee, the value of `isRetired` is always `false`. Because Java does not find an appropriate setter, the value of a boolean field is always default value, say `false`, which is not expected.

```
class Employee{
    private int age;
    private boolean isRetired;

    ...
    public boolean setRetired(boolean isRetired){
        this.isRetired = isRetired;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
private boolean current;

public void setCurrent(boolean current){
    this.current=current;
}

public boolean hasCurrent(){
    return this.current;
}
```

Comment: has current what? I think `has` used for BO or such a service with some processing while for POJO it is `is`. and please add some description about your answer.

Answer (score -5):

```
Setter: public void setCurrent(boolean val)
Getter: public boolean getCurrent()
```

For booleans you can also use

```
public boolean isCurrent()
```

Comment: Because the OP states a question about boolean values. A getter prefixed with 'get' is (read: should) never be used for boolean values.

Answer (score -6):

As a setter, how about:

```
// setter
public void beCurrent(boolean X) {
    this.isCurrent = X;
}
```

or

```
// setter
public void makeCurrent(boolean X) {
    this.isCurrent = X;
}
```

I'm not sure if these naming make sense to native English speakers.

Comment: They don't really make sence

Comment: But sounds phonetically maybe promising with some attributes :)