# Boolean(Object) getters in java

Tags: java, coding-style

Lets say I have class `foo` in which I have a `Boolean` (not `boolean`) variable `bar`:

```
class foo {
    Boolean bar;

    Boolean isBar(){
        return bar;
    }

    boolean isBar(){
        return bar.booleanValue();
    }
}
```

Which of the above methods is the right way in Java.

I know both will work but I want to know what is the coding convention in Java regarding this matter?

Comment: Well do you *want* to return `Boolean` or `boolean`? If you're returning `boolean`, how would you handle `bar` being `null`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you will actualy be using the Boolean type your method should be

```
Boolean getBar(){
    return bar;
}
```

otherwise your field should be the primitive boolean type.

Comment: He's not asking for name conventions. He's asking `bar.booleanValue();` vs `return bar;`. It's a good note, but it doesn't answer the question. (Or I misunderstood the question :))

Comment: Getters for booleans can be prefixed with either `get` or `is`, so the naming is ok, but that's not what he's asking.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322648/for-a-boolean-field-what-is-the-naming-convention-for-its-getter-setter) discusses that point and recommends using `isX`... as would I.

Comment: I think "getBar" is more appropriate here,as Boolean is explicitly an object and also can be "null". It's not about true or false here, it's about true, false and "no state" ;)

Comment: you guys are right, i did interpret the question wrong, changed the answer accordingly. As for naming convention, imho, primitve booleans should be prefixed "is","should" or can. Object Booleans should be prefixed with get.

Answer (score 3):

a `boolean` is a primitive, it can be `true` or `false`. [Boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) is an *object wrapper* for `boolean`. `Boolean` can be *true*, *false* and *null*. Unless you need this `null`, use `boolean` since it's cheaper for memory.

`Boolean` has many helper methods, for example, you can have a Boolean from a String by using `Boolean.valueOf(theString);` which can be "false" or "true", instead of doing

```
if("true".equals(theString)) 
    primitiveBoolean = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless `bar` can be `null`, and this is something you want to model in your class, I would use:

```
class foo {
    boolean bar;

    boolean isBar(){
        return bar;
    }
}
```

It's simpler, faster and can't have `NullPointerException`s.

If, however, `null` is a valid value and you want model that, you should use `Boolean`/`Boolean`.

Note that your code:

```
Boolean bar;

boolean isBar() {
    return bar.booleanValue();
}
```

Or even the autoboxing variant:

```
Boolean bar;

boolean isBar() {
    return bar;
}
```

...may throw `NullPointerException`s. Especially the last one is very confusing.

Comment: Good point - what is the reason for having `Boolean` as the instance variable anyway?

Comment: Boolean as an Object is a "good" way to have 3 states, for instance "On", "Off" and "Doesn't Matter"

Comment: @Adrian, G-Man: Yes, this is what I tried to express with if "null is a valid value and you want model that"