# JavaFX BooleanProperty cant not be mapped in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Firstly, i have read this thread : [JavaFX BooleanProperty and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979073/javafx-booleanproperty-and-hibernate)
and couldn't solve my Problem.

My Class Article (not the full class though)

```
public Article() {
    private BooleanProperty en = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    //getter Methode:
    public boolean isEn(){
         return en.get();
    }
    public BooleanProperty enProperty(){
         return en;
    }
    public void setEn(boolean en){
         this.en.set(en);
    }
}
```

my mapping XML :

```
<property column="b_english_version" name="en" type="javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty"/>
```

And i get this Problem

> MappingException : Could not determine type for: javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty, at table t_fit_article, for columns: ... b_english_version]

but when i Change the type to **boolean** then its no longer wrong.

Can someone explain why ?