# Naming convention for a getter of a boolean with a specific name?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I have the following member in a class:

```
private boolean requireColons;
```

I am aware that the convention is to prefix all boolean getters with `is` but `isRequireColons()` doesn't make sense. How should I name this?

Comment: `isRequireColons()` makes *programming* sense whether or not it makes 100% grammatical sense.

Comment: And *if* you change the variable name to `colonRequired` then the `is...` will fit as well.

Comment: I would rather stick to the convention. But if you are so worried about wrong/bad sounding grammar in a getter name why not rename the boolean to `colonsRequired` and you will get `isColonsRequired` which doesn't sound that bad ;)

Comment: How about `requiresColons`?

Comment: `isRequiredColons()` fits well i think

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5322666/1715121

Comment: @EleazarEnrique You do realize I mention this exact convention in my question?

Comment: Yes, I did.  The link is to get knowedge about *Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language* and to help other people that probably will visit your question.

Comment: In that case, you should have just directly linked said convention.

Comment: You could do `isColonRequired` (but then its no longer plural).

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
isColonsRequired
```

but if you're looking for the more grammatically correct (but less programmatically) alternative

```
areColonsRequired
```