# What should be the name of getter method for a boolean variable starting with `is`

Tags: java, naming-conventions, getter-setter

I have below member variable `mIsMobilePresent` where starting with `m` is the convention we follow to identify that it is a member variable.

My question what should be the name of the getter of this variable?

`getIsMobilePresent` or `getIsMobilePresent` or `isMobilePresent`

Comment: you can view this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322648/for-a-boolean-field-what-is-the-naming-convention-for-its-getter-setter

Comment: It should be `isIsMobilePresent()`, just like it should be `isIsland()` if the boolean field is called `island`. But you shouldn’t name your field `isMobilePresent`, because the type of it already indicates that it’s a boolean. Just like you shouldn’t prefix your fields with ‘m’ because that’s implicit already and any half-decent IDE will show fields in a different color or font style. Just follow the Java Coding Conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in Java we usually don't tag member variables with an "m" prefix.

The usual (Java Bean) convention is the variable be named

```
boolean mobilePresent
```

and the getter

```
public boolean isMobilePresent
```

Alternatively, a `has`-prefix can be used

```
public boolean hasConfiguredMobileConnections;
```

[Where is the JavaBeans naming convention defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991316/where-is-the-javabean-property-naming-convention-defined)

Answer: [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138795.html) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf).