# Naming convention for boolean field to avoid variable name conflict

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions, javabeans

I have an `Employee` class. It needs a boolean flag to tell if this employee is a manager.

From this question [For a boolean field, what is the naming convention for its getter/setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322648/for-a-boolean-field-what-is-the-naming-convention-for-its-getter-setter) 
I understand that the naming conversion is to name the variable as `X` and the getter as `isX`. So my `Employee` class would be like this

```
class Employee {
  boolean manager; 

  boolean isManager(){
    return this.manager;
  }
}
```

But the name `manager` is confusing to me. The word `manager` is a noun, not an adjective, like `active`, `current`, `open` in [the above question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322648/for-a-boolean-field-what-is-the-naming-convention-for-its-getter-setter). `manager` could be a boolean flag or a manager object. Furthermore, if I do want a member variable for the manager in the `Employee` class, the `manager` variable name is already taken for the flag.

```
class Employee {
  boolean manager; 

  boolean isManager(){
    return this.manager;
  }

  //Employee manager; //don't know how to name this
}
```

Is there another way to name the boolean manager flag in this case? Thanks

Comment: You could call it `isManager`. The Java Beans conventions are a little strange hereabouts.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a two-value enum in place of a boolean:

```
class Employee {
    enum Type { REGULAR, MANAGER }

    Type type = Type.REGULAR;
    Employee manager;

    Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    Employee getManager() {
        return manager;
    }
}
```

One could also use `Role` or `Level` instead of Type, both in the enum name and in the get-method name.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the real conflict here is at the data modelling level.

- An Employee *is-a* manager (the boolean flag)
- An Employee *has-a* manager (the Employee valued field)

There are two (possibly) different "manager" concepts with the same name.  So how do we deal with this (apparent) conflict at the model level?

- We could ignore it.
- We could simply rename one or other of the concepts.  But that is a bad idea because the two concepts are probably intimately related<sup>1</sup>.
- We could drill down on the concepts; i.e. is there a significant (to the model) difference between "being a person with manager status" and "being in the role of manager for another person".  This *could* tell us that the concepts are sufficiently different that they *need* to have different names.

So assuming that we ignore it at the modeling level, how do we deal with it at the Java level?  Here are a couple of suggestions:

Version #1 has two distinct properties with the same name.  This is probably a violation of the JavaBeans convention ... at least as most people understand it.

```
  public class Employee {
      private boolean isManager;
      private Employee manager;  

      public boolean isManager(){
        return this.isManager;
      }

      public Employee getManager(){
        return this.manager;
      }
  }
```

Version #2 tweaks the property names.  For example, use "manager" and "aManager":

```
  public class Employee {
      private boolean isManager;
      private Employee manager;  

      public boolean isAManager(){
        return this.isManager;
      }

      public Employee getManager(){
        return this.manager;
      }
  }
```

Or you could tweak the other property name.

---

<sup>1 - For example, in UML terms you could model the "manager" Attribute as *derived* from the Association that relates an employee to their manager.  The attribute value can be derived by testing if this employee is a manager of any another employee via the association.</sup>

Comment: The `is-a` and `has-a` explain the problem very clearly to me. But I don't quite understand the difference between Version #1 and Version #2. And Version #2 will have compilation error in `getManager` method.

Comment: The compilation error was a typo.  Fixed.  The difference between versions #1 and #2 is that version #1 is NOT JavaBeans compliant, and *might* cause problems in some contexts; e.g. runtime errors because some framework has problems binding the `Employee` class because of the "two properties with the same name".

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question! ...as I also been struggling with this kinda thing for years, and yet still not able to find the best formulation for it.  How about naming the boolean variable with the noun + `"Typed"` suffix, and stick with the `"is"` + Noun for the getter? So you would get:

```java
class Employee {
  boolean managerTyped;

  boolean isManager() {
    return this.managerTyped;
  }

  Employee manager;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

How about something like this?

```
class Employee {
    Employee manager;

    boolean isManager(){
        return (manager != null && manager instanceof Manager);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the correct semantic.  It makes more sense if `isManager` returns true if this person has manager status and `getManager` returns the person who manages this person.

Comment: Oh OK, I understand now. Why don't you name your flag `isManager` just like the method and maybe make the flag `private`.