# Lombok @Data annotation changes the name of a field from isood to good

Tags: java, annotations, getter, lombok, setter

I have this DTO which uses `@Data` annotation of `lombok` in order to generate `getters` and `setters`:

```
@Data
public class SomeDto {

  protected boolean isGood;
}
```

The weird thing is that now my getter has been renamed from `getisGood()` to `isGood()` and the setter has the name `setGood()` instead of `setIsGood()`.
Example:

```
SomeDto somedto = new SomeDto()
somedto.setGood(false) //sets the value to false - should have been setIsGood
somedto.isGood() //return false - should have been getIsGood
```

Also when I make a request on the endpoint where I use this DTO in the JSON returns:

```
{"good": false}
```

whereas is should has been :

```
{"isGood": false}
```

Anyone has any idea what the problem is? I have a suspicion that the "is" in the beginning of `isGood` creates maybe a confusion for lombok. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: you could change boolean to Boolean, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381474/cant-make-jackson-and-lombok-work-together.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the convention is that for a boolean, the getter is called isGood, while the setter is setGood. So your boolean is expected to be called just "good".

[Here is one discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322648/for-a-boolean-field-what-is-the-naming-convention-for-its-getter-setter)

Also in the documentation :)

```
 lombok.getter.noIsPrefix = [true | false] (default: false)
    If set to true, getters generated for boolean fields will use the get prefix instead of the defaultis prefix, and any generated code that calls getters, such as @ToString, will also use get instead of is
```

[Docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter)